# Number of solutions and minimal clues in Sixy Sudoku

Tags: permutations, symmetry, latin-square, sudoku

**Sixy Sudoku** is a variation on Latin squares and traditional sudoku played on a $6 \times 6$ grid with an initial clue of several cells filled in with a subset of the digits $1$–$6$.  The task is to fill in the remaining cells such that each digit appears once in each

- $1 \times 6$ row
- $6 \times 1$ column
- $2 \times 3$ shaded rectangle
- $3 \times 2$ outlined rectangle

[image]

**Questions**

- Given a grid with no initial filled cells, how many valid filled grids, $K$, exist (up to digit-permutation symmetry)?
- What is the minimum number of filled cells, $n^*$, that guarantees a unique puzzle solution?
- For that minimum $n^*$, how many distinct placements of filled cells ensure a unique solution (up to digit-permutation symmetry)?

For the first problem, without loss of generality, we can set the digits in the upper-left shaded rectangle as shown here:

[image]

Guided by @GerardPaseman (below), we can see that there are $2^7$ ways to fill the top half of the puzzle (given the assigned upper-left shaded rectangle):  The top row has $2^2$ alternatives (given all constraints), and the second row has $2^2$ alternatives.  The third row has $2^3$ alternatives.  Putting together:  $2^7$.  But then there are the cells in the bottom half of the puzzle.  The naive (but slightly tighter) bound is thus $(2^7)^2$.

The red show the number of independent alternatives in some of the cells starting at the right top shaded rectangle, then beneath it, then moving to the left:

[image]

(The blue arrows show the sequence of cell fillings using all prior constraints.  One can work in a different sequence of cell constraints, if desired.)

For the last two problems it will be interesting to see how close the information defined by the number of minimal filled cells, $n^*$ (where $n^* \geq 5$ for digit specification), and candidate placements approximates the information bound given by $K$.

---

**Addendum**:

Today's **Sixy Sudoku** puzzle in *The New York Times magazine* is a variation on the traditional puzzle in which the bordered rectangles are replaced by $6$-element locking polyominoes, as shown:

[image: 5-clue puzzle]

I confirmed that this puzzle is solvable.  Note that it has just $n=5$ clue cells.  This *suggests* (but of course doesn't prove) that $n^* = 5$ for the traditional rectangular Sixy Sudoku.

Comment: Have you looked at 'Taking Sudoku Seriously', by Rosenhouse and Taalman?  They work out answers to analogous questions for 4 by 4 Sudoku.

Comment: @Stopple:  Yes, I have read ***Taking Sudoku seriously***---a wonderful book.  My problem is a bit different from the one they treated in the extend of the constraints.

Comment: There are  32 ways to fill the top remaining twelve squares, and 729 ways to fill the remaining squares for each of the 32 ways. I suspect the constraints will eliminate at least 2/3 of these combinations, leaving less than 8000 possibilities. A brute force breadth first search by computer should answer all of your questions. Gerhard "Small Is The New Big" Paseman, 2019.10.07.

Comment: No. I am upper bounding. The top three squares admit four possibilities, as do the second row (so 128, not 32, sorry for the mistake). The eight possibilities for the third row should be obvious. Then column constraints give 6^6 (instead of 3^6) ways to fill the bottom half. So I was off by a factor 2^8, but still this is well within computer search. I am not using all constraints. Gerhard "729 Times 8192 Still Small" Paseman, 2019.10.07.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman:  Yes...  I also got $2^7$ alternatives for the upper-half.  (I tried to get your $32$ and thought *I* was wrong!)  True, a computer search should be feasible for determining $K$, but I think it will be unfeasible (on a laptop) for $n^*$.  Regardless, we should strive for a principled, analytic solution whenever possible.  How to incorporate all these constraints is more important than the raw numerical solution.  But thanks!

Comment: If you start with the middle top 3 by 2 outlined region, those constraints allow 576 placements for the middle two columns and middle two rows. Now the lower right 2 by 2 square will have three possibilities. This constrains two other 2by2 corner squares to (I think) two choices each, and I believe this constrains the diagonally opposite 2by2. This is 6912 choices when given an initial six placement arrangement of the top middle outlined rectangle.  Gerhard "Is Leaving Out Much Detail" Paseman, 2019.10.07.

Comment: Silly question: do you have a source of these? Some elementary searching finds lots of irrelevant links and no hits.

Comment: @DavidRoberts:  Not silly at all.  Sixy Sudoku puzzles are printed ever week in the *Sunday New York Times magazine*.  Also, see here:  https://www.amazon.com/Sixy-Sudoku-%E2%97%8F%E2%97%8F%E2%97%8F-Medium-Puzzles/dp/1095354329 and page 67 here:  https://issuu.com/paulguarino710/docs/nyt_magazine_-_09.22.2019

Comment: You may try a variation on the backtracking implementation in appendix B of the thesis of Bastian Michel https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~kalle101/webfiles/sudoku.pdf

Comment: @WilberdvanderKallen:  Thanks for the pointer.  Yes, there are a number of computer methods to address these problems, and I may have to write my own code for the $n^*$ problem.  I was hoping there was a principled mathematical approach.  For instance, I thought the problem could be factored into multiple independent sub-problems, and then integrated with constraints.  I'll keep working...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork thanks. For some reason I read it as **Sixty** not **Sixy**, no wonder I couldn't find anything on them :-/.

Comment: @WilberdvanderKallen:  Thanks so very much for the coding and number of solutions.  It supports my partial analyses that the number of solutions is rather small and suggests one needs only $11$ bits to specify a constrained problem.  Can your code be modified to answer questions $2$ and $3$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Questions 2 and 3 would take more. But notice that my code accepts any initial data. So one can experiment to get a feeling. The code will be cleaned a bit, by the way.

Comment: @WilberdvanderKallen:  Thanks.  But I know that $n^* \leq 7$, as the first puzzle I showed proves.  How'd you get your $8$?

Comment: @WilberdvanderKallen:  Addendum:  $5 \leq n^* \leq 7$.

Comment: @WilberdvanderKallen:  I would start by searching for $n^* = 5$ puzzles because if there is one, that proves the bound is tight.  There are only $36 \cdot 35 \cdot 34 \cdot 33 \cdot 32 \approx 4.5 \times 10^7$ such cases (fewer if one exploits spatial symmetries), and should be exhaustively searchable.  This would also give the answer to my third question.

Answer (score 2):

As for the first question, a backtracking algorithm, see sixy.c at

https://github.com/wilberdk/sixy

shows there are 1936 completions of

$$\matrix{1&2&3&4&5&6\cr
*&*&*&*&*& *\cr
*&*&*&*&*&*\cr
*&*&*&*&*&*\cr
*&*&*&*&*&*\cr
*&*&*&*&*&*&}$$

The answer to the second question is $n^*=7$. 
The answer to the third question is $908\,928$.
These are more tricky. For instance, 
there are 2752 ways to chose five cells in

$$\matrix{
*&*&*&*&*& *\cr
*&*&*&*&*& *\cr
*&*&6&*&*&*\cr
*&*&*&*&*&*\cr
*&*&*&*&6&*\cr
*&*&*&*&*&*}$$
to construct an initial clue like
$$\matrix{
*&*&*&*&*& *\cr
*&*&*&*&*& 1\cr
*&*&6&*&2&*\cr
*&3&*&*&*&*\cr
*&4&*&*&6&5\cr
*&*&*&*&*&*}$$
that ensures a unique solution.
Here the construction fills the chosen cells with 1 through 5 consistent with the lexicographic order.

One sees that $n^*=7$ by replacing 
$$\matrix{
*&*&*&*&*& *\cr
*&*&*&*&*& *\cr
*&*&6&*&*&*\cr
*&*&*&*&*&*\cr
*&*&*&*&6&*\cr
*&*&*&*&*&*}$$
with  starting configurations that have just one filled cell. 
There is a symmetry group $G$ of order 128 with just three orbits of cells, and we tried all 6 times 3 orbits of 
configurations that have just one filled cell. The group $G$ is generated by the following three operations: 
turn the grid upside down; reflect the grid in the main diagonal; interchange the first two rows.

To be more specific about the answer to the third question, 
let us  make some definitions.
Call a clue valid, if it has seven filled cells and a unique solution.
Given a valid clue, its core is obtained by deleting all integers that occur only once.
The core size of a valid clue is the number of filled cells in its core.
For instance the core size of 
$$\matrix{
*&*&*&*&*& *\cr
*&*&*&*&*& 1\cr
*&*&6&*&2&*\cr
*&3&*&*&*&*\cr
*&4&*&*&6&5\cr
*&*&*&*&*&*}$$
is two.
Possible core sizes are two, three and four.

One tries all $G$-orbits of possible cores.

There are $6!$ times $396\,800$ valid clues with core size 2 and they form $6!$ times $12\,242$ $G$-orbits.

There are $6!$ times $16\,000$ valid clues with core size 3 and they form $6!$ times $226$ $G$-orbits.

There are $6!$ times $496\,128$ valid clues with core size 4 and they form $6!/2$ times $5320$ orbits under a group which is twice as large as $G$.

$396800 + 16000 + 496128 = 908928$.

The programs we wrote for this task can be found at

https://github.com/wilberdk/sixy

Comment: Hmmm... Could you show an $n^* = 7$ solution?  And how have you shown $n^* \neq 6$?